# Can we get some thousands separators?

Tags: feature-request, wording, site-analytics

**Disclaimer:** This post is very nitpicky. If you dislike that please move along.

---

If one visits *https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics*, but lacks the required reputation they are served the following text:

> #### This page requires more privileges
>
> ---
>
> The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege “Access to site analytics.”
>
> You receive additional privileges on Meta Stack Exchange by earning more reputation through participation on the site. When you have earned at least 25000 reputation, you will receive the “Access to site analytics” privilege and will be allowed to view this page.
>
> Visit the privileges page to learn more about the privileges you can earn.

**Can we give this 25000 value a thousands separator to be consistent with the rest of the network?**

---

The above page also includes a link to *https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation* which also features a thousand without a separator:

> ......
> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> - question is voted up: +10
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

**Can this 1000 also get a thousands separator?**

<sup><sub>Thanks to [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) for finding the second example.</sub></sup>

Comment: International standard thousand separator (space) ?

Comment: @Tensibai I don't think there is one universal standard. Both `.`, `,` and space are used. Seeing that SE uses `.` I think it is best to be consistent with that.

Comment: There's is an universal standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#General_rules (and it has choosen space because dot and commas are likely to cause confusion depending on where you're from and your local usage)

Comment: Quote from the page above to avoid the click for everyone: "Spaces should be used as a thousands separator (1 000 000) in contrast to commas or periods (1,000,000 or 1.000.000) to reduce confusion resulting from the variation between these forms in different countries."

Comment: @Tensibai that would be a different feature request I guess, as that would mean changing an awful lot of text scattered over an awful lot of pages.

Comment: Agree, al in all it boilds down to using a locale formatting for all numbers (which would solve this FR if using en_US) and use a locale complying with SI units. (all in all that may be a good approach to solve a bunch of problems for high numbers before Jon Skeet breaks the next multiplicator :D)

Comment: @Luuklag does SE really use `.`? The numbers on the [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) use `,` as a thousands separator, at least on my browser.

Comment: You are correct @wimi